# jekyll yaml front-matter is turned into <hr> tag by markdown

Tags: html, github, yaml, jekyll

My jekyll YAML header infomation can't be rightly parse by github page server.

my blog markdown file under _posts is named 2014-08-28-just-build-my-blog-site.md, and it's like:

```
---
layout: post
title: just build my blog site
---
Hello World. goodbye *lofter*.
```

The markdown file can be rightly turned into html in my local jekyll server. But when I upload my post to github. github turn the "---" in md file into

```
<hr>
```

html tag.

Why the jekyll of my local computer can rightly parse my markdown file, but the jekyll of github can't. What should I do? Thanks first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text editor is saving files in an 'unknown' encoding. Maybe chinese.
Try to encode as utf-8 it's a standard for Jekyll

Comment: I use notepad++ to edit the markdown files and the notepad++ is set to UTF-8 mode already. Now I parse the markdown files in local computer, and upload the parsed html files to github, Thanks any way.

Comment: finally I find another online editor and solve this problem. Thank you. Maybe you are right.